# Here JavaScript API 3.x - Autocomplete function

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm just wondering if there is a similar functionality in Here JS API 3.x   for auto completion as in the google API.

In connection with the google maps API there is an autocomplete class available where you simply pass the UI element that is used for rendering the results of auto completion.

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( 
                          (map_searchbox) , {componentRestrictions: countryRestrict });
```

As far as I have seen there is no such functionality available in the Here JS API 3.x. Did I miss it maybe? However, there is also the places API (H.places.Search) that can be used for searching and the jQuery Autocomplete widget could be used for displaying the results.

I'm just struggling a bit with the usage of the places API. I want to do the following in connection with searching for addresses only:

Pass the center of e.g. Germany in order to search for a specific street in any city inside Germany. As a result, I would expect that all those cities are returned. But it doesn't work like this with the Search entrypoint (https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places/topics_api/resource-search.html)

Passing the center of Germany (coordinates 51.163375,10.447683) and searching for "Gotthardstraße" does not return Munich as city. Also, the search entrypoint does not offer the "in" parameter where you could specify a bounding box or polygon.

Could someone maybe give me some hints how to realize a similar auto complete functionality with the Here JS API 3.x? Integration into jQuery does not need to be answered. I'm just wondering about the correct usage of the Here JS API 3.x.

Thanks for your help, Seppal

Comment: Did I describe what I'm looking for in an understandable way? If not clear, please just let me know. Many thanks, Seppal

Answer (score 1):

HERE now also offers a **Geocoder Autocomplete API**.

The API has been available for licensing for a while, but the documentation was only recently made public: [Geocoder Autocomplete API Developer's Guide - Introduction](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/topics/introduction.html).

That API is an alternative to the Places API "suggest" feature. It provides address results even for short inputs (starting at two characters). Search can be restricted to the current map view or to a specific region for better results.

Comment: The documentation for the API is now publicly available on the [Developer Portal](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/topics/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

@hurrassinger,Here Maps API 3.x does provide "suggest" similar to autocomplete.

In Places API -> there is Suggest Entry point. (Instead of search that you are using)

> The Suggest Entrypoint represents lists of suggested search terms related to a given (partial) search term and location context. This entrypoint is used to help users to provide suggested search terms to the user while typing.

Please refer https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places/topics_api/resource-suggest.html

Now **In javascript API** , refer PlacesService class. This class implements Places api access (and access to suggest entry point). This class has a method called as suggest. (page 494 in [this document](https://developer.here.com/documentation/download/maps_js_html5_nlp/3.0.5/Maps%20API%20for%20JavaScript%20v3.0.5%20Developer%27s%20Guide.pdf) )

Hope this helps.

Comment: Due to a longer vacation I'm late with my answer (sorry for that). Many thanks for your answer though and the hint!

Unfortunately, same "issue" as with the Search Entry Point. When I search for "Gotthardstr." in Munich, it is not returned. Only the "Gotthardstr." in "Gotha" is listed. Google also shows this street in cities like Passau, Munich, Berlin, ... Any other ideas/hints?